# Show Label if field1 + field2 = x

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-10.4, vbscript

I'm trying to show a label if a field + another field = a certain value. Not sure the proper way to do this. I've tried cint([field1]) + cint([field2]) = x  but that doesn't work either.  It says the expression is valid but the feature that meets the criteria is not labelled.

```vbs
Function FindLabel ( [SQFT_CONC] , [DEPTH_CONC] , [SQFT_ASPHT] , [DEPTH_ASHT]  )
  Dim strInput
  if [DEPTH_CONC] + [DEPTH_ASHT] = 10 then
     strInput = "IT WORKS"
  end if

  FindLabel = strInput
End Function
```

Comment: what happens when you try this?  what version of ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.4.1  - It says the expression is valid but the feature that meets the criteria is not labeled.

Comment: There is an [edit] button beneath your question so that you can update it with any requested clarifications like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CInt` should have worked for you - I wrote mine slightly different, but it works:

```vbs
Function FindLabel ( [SQFT_CONC] , [DEPTH_CONC] , [SQFT_ASPHT] , [DEPTH_ASHT]  )
  Dim strInput
  Dim dc
  Dim da
  dc = CInt([DEPTH_CONC])
  da = CInt([DEPTH_ASHT])
  val = dc + da
  if (val = 10) then
     strInput = "IT WORKS"
  end if

  FindLabel = strInput
End Function
```

I'd also recommend you look into using Python parser for labelling - I find you have a bit more control of things using python.

```py
def FindLabel ([SQFT_CONC] , [DEPTH_CONC] , [SQFT_ASPHT] , [DEPTH_ASHT]  ):
  if int([DEPTH_CONC) + int([DEPTH_ASHT]) == 10:
    return "IT WORKS!!"
  else:
    return ""
```

---

To treat `Null` values as `0` check for `Null` and substitute a `0` into the variable.

```vbs
Function FindLabel ( [SQFT_CONC] , [DEPTH_CONC] , [SQFT_ASPHT] , [DEPTH_ASHT]  )
  Dim strInput
  Dim dc
  Dim da
  if isNull([DEPTH_CONC]) then
    dc = 0
  else
    dc = CInt([DEPTH_CONC])
  end if
  if isNull([DEPTH_ASHT]) then
    da = 0
  else
    da = CInt([DEPTH_ASHT])
  end if
  val = dc + da
  if (val = 10) then
     strInput = "IT WORKS"
  end if

  FindLabel = strInput
End Function
```

To ignore records completely, step over them in an `if` statement if either value is `Null`

```vbs
Function FindLabel ( [SQFT_CONC] , [DEPTH_CONC] , [SQFT_ASPHT] , [DEPTH_ASHT]  )
  Dim strInput
  Dim dc
  Dim da
  if not isNull([DEPTH_CONC]) and not isNull([DEPTH_ASHT]) then
    dc = CInt([DEPTH_CONC])
    da = CInt([DEPTH_ASHT])
    val = dc + da
    if (val = 10) then
       strInput = "IT WORKS"
    end if
  end if
  FindLabel = strInput
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! This will be much easier to implement. CInt did end up working for me in the end though, I'm not really sure what I messed up in my previous attempts.

Comment: Now I have an issue, what do I do when I have fields that are null? I get an error when I verify my expression.

Comment: @Ryan I'll update my answer shortly when I'm back in the office

Comment: @Ryan how would you like to treat the Null fields?  As if they were 0, or ignore the record completely?

Comment: as if they were 0,  [I figured out how to do it](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211192/72465) , out of curiosity how would I ignore those records completely?

Comment: @Ryan I've updated for both scenarios

Comment: Thanks, isn't this a shorter way to do the same thing subbing zero? [http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211192/72465](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/211192/72465)

Comment: @Ryan in this scenario possibly it is, but it may not stand in every situation.  Safer to actually search for Null values and handle them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it didn't work the first time I tried it this way but seemed to do the trick the 10th time around?

[image]