# Handling NULL values when using CInt?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-10.4, vbscript

This expression works perfectly when integer fields are 0 instead of NULL but now I am working with a GDB that has many NULL values. I'm not sure how to force CInt to only run if field is not null.

[image: Error message]

```vb
Function FindLabel ( [SQFT_CONC] , [DEPTH_CONC] , [SQFT_ASPHT] , [DEPTH_ASHT]  )
  Dim strInput
  Dim dc
  Dim da
  dc = CInt([DEPTH_CONC])
  da = CInt([DEPTH_ASHT])
  val = dc + da
  if (val = 10) then
     strInput = "IT WORKS"
  end if

  FindLabel = strInput
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct way do handle this. If the field is `Null` then it will count as a `0`. This first way is shorter although I'm not sure if it will give the desired result in every scenario.

```vb
Function FindLabel ( [SQFT_CONC] , [DEPTH_CONC] , [SQFT_ASPHT] , [DEPTH_ASHT]  )
  Dim strInput
  Dim dc
  Dim da
  dc = CInt(0 & [DEPTH_CONC])
  da = CInt(0 & [DEPTH_ASHT])
  val = dc + da
  if (val = 10) then
     strInput = "IT WORKS"
  end if

  FindLabel = strInput
End Function
```

Alternatively....

To treat `Null` values as `0` check for `Null` and substitute a `0` into the variable.

```vbs
Function FindLabel ( [SQFT_CONC] , [DEPTH_CONC] , [SQFT_ASPHT] , [DEPTH_ASHT]  )
  Dim strInput
  Dim dc
  Dim da
  if isNull([DEPTH_CONC]) then
    dc = 0
  else
    dc = CInt([DEPTH_CONC])
  end if
  if isNull([DEPTH_ASHT]) then
    da = 0
  else
    da = CInt([DEPTH_ASHT])
  end if
  val = dc + da
  if (val = 10) then
     strInput = "IT WORKS"
  end if

  FindLabel = strInput
End Function
```

To ignore records completely, step over them in an `if` statement if either value is `Null`

```vbs
Function FindLabel ( [SQFT_CONC] , [DEPTH_CONC] , [SQFT_ASPHT] , [DEPTH_ASHT]  )
  Dim strInput
  Dim dc
  Dim da
  if not isNull([DEPTH_CONC]) and not isNull([DEPTH_ASHT]) then
    dc = CInt([DEPTH_CONC])
    da = CInt([DEPTH_ASHT])
    val = dc + da
    if (val = 10) then
       strInput = "IT WORKS"
    end if
  end if
  FindLabel = strInput
End Function
```